# Visual basic progress bar keeps going below 0

Tags: vb.net

I am making a small game and the problem is that the spell attack does to much damage and goes negative but i have created an IF statement that makes the damage = 0 if the value of the progress bar goes below 0 but it still does it i am really confused

```
Private Sub Btnspell_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 

 Btnspell.Click
    sdamage = spell.Next(5, 10)


    If Playermana.Value < 20 Then
        Playermana.Value = Playermana.Value - 0
    End If

    If Playermana.Value <= 19 Then
        MsgBox("Not enough mana")
    End If
    If farmerhealth.Value > 0 Then
        farmerhealth.Value = farmerhealth.Value - sdamage
        Playermana.Value = Playermana.Value - 20
        Timer1.Start()


    End If
    If farmerhealth.Value <= 0 Then
        MsgBox("You have killed the farmer")
        sdamage = 0
        farmerhealth.Value = farmerhealth.Value + 0

    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Is `farmerhealth` the progress bar?  Is it throwing an exception?

Comment: _Really_ long shot: You start a timer.  Is `sdamage` used in that timer to continually apply damage?  Does the timer update the progress bar?  Is the code above the _only_ check for `farmerhealth.Value <= 0` - ie does the timer continue to apply damage regardless of what the health is?

Comment: In the first if statement you are subtracting `0` from the `Playermana.Value` and later you are adding `0` to the `farmerhead.Value`.  Why?  Look at my answer for a correction for your progress bar, but these operations don't do anything.

Comment: By the way, since each `If` is not nested in the former statement, if you don't have enough mana you'll print the message, but the next if will be checked and executed, so the attack will be done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated to avoid `HP` name**:

I think your value still goes to negative values cause you have:

```
 If farmerhealth.Value > 0 Then
    farmerhealth.Value = farmerhealth.Value - sdamage
    Playermana.Value = Playermana.Value - 20
    Timer1.Start()
 End If
```

Here, if you for example have `farmerhealth.Value = 1`, you do the damage, but it can be `sdamage = 7`, so it goes negative (`farmerhealth.Value - sdamage` would return `-6`).

Just check if `farmerhealth.Value - sdamage` is negative inside this statement, then give the value 0 instead to `farmerhealth.Value`.

**Update 2:** Then it should end being something like this:

```
 If farmerhealth.Value > 0 Then
    If (farmerhealth.Value - sdamage) <= 0 then
      farmerhealth.Value = 0
    else
      farmerhealth.Value = farmerhealth.Value - sdamage
    End If
    Playermana.Value = Playermana.Value - 20
    Timer1.Start()
 End If
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was typing, great minds think alike! one suggestion though, I've found that using a subroutine with a progress bar and an integer value as parameters works best for setting progressbars. inside the subroutine you can check if the value is less than the minimum or greater than the maximum of the progressbar, and set the value accordingly.

Comment: That's a good point @RianBattle, when you're working with items which need always to check special conditions like here.

Comment: i do not have anything controlling HP, HP is the value of the progress bar so the value is set to 100

Comment: Think about the elements, not how I named them, @billy. Anyway, I updated the answer using your values and variables.

Comment: I am still stuck on what code to add sorry im not very advance with programming and im trying to learn by myself sorry if this is annoying you